# In Unity, how can I hide the global menu on an application running fullscreen in a second monitor?

Tags: unity, 12.10, xinerama

I often play video content on my second screen, and I've noticed that when the fullscreen application loses focus (i.e. I go back to doing something on my main screen) a global menu bar appears above it. I find that distracting -- is there some way to prevent the menu bar from appearing in that context?

Answer (score 0):

Install [CompizConfig Settings Manager [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) if you don't have it installed in your system.

<sup>To do that, either click the link or open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.</sup>

Then open CompizConfig Settings Manager (by running the `ccsm`), select "**Ubuntu Unity Plugin**" if you dont find it search for it in the search toolbar. In **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** select the  "**Experimental**" tab, adjust the menus-fade in/out time duration according to whatever you want.

Comment: Menu fade-in/fade-out duration doesn't seem to have any effect on this. My goal is to set things up such that, while an application is fullscreen on one monitor, no system/menu bar displays on that screen at all (until the application is no longer fullscreened).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a solution or just workaround, but I found this to work pretty well. I do have exactly the same problem. Dual monitors and when one app is in fullscreen on one monitor, but loses focus, the app menu appears over it. Simply right click on the menu and toggle 'Always on top'. It works not only with vlc, but also with a firefox window and fullscreen youtube etc.

Comment: When I used full screen Firefox and used the menu in another application in my main display, the menu also appeared over the full screen browser. This answer solved the problem. I don't know why was it downvoted.